# Batch class is not updating Accounts in the Test class

Tags: apex, batch

I have below batch class which just updates the account name, which is working fine:

```
global class BatchClass3 implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        String query = 'Select Name from Account';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> records)
    {
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        for(Account acc : records)
        {
            acc.Name=acc.Name+' Updated by Batch';
            accounts.add(acc);
        }
        update accounts;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
    }
}
```

When I wrote the below test class and executed it, it is giving the below error:

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: Account 1 Updated
>   by Batch, Actual: Account 1.

This means that the Accounts are not getting updated. Can you please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
@isTest
private class BatchTest
{
    static testMethod void testBatch()
    {
        List<Account> accs = new List<Account>();
        for(Integer i=1;i<=6;i++)
        {
            Account a = new Account();
            a.Name='Account '+i;
            accs.add(a);
        }
        insert accs;
        Test.startTest();
            Database.executeBatch(new BatchClass3());
            System.assertEquals(6, [Select count() from Account]);
            //System.assertEquals('Account 1 Updated by Batch',[Select Name from Account limit 1][0].Name);
            Integer i=1;
            for(Account a : [Select Name from Account] )
            {
                System.assertEquals('Account '+i+' Updated by Batch', a.Name);
                i++;
            }
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: You add the assertion after the `Test.stoptest()` line to be sure the batch has finished.

Comment: You need to make sure you query the ID of the accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynchronous apex is executed after executing the `Test.stopTest()` line i.e. All asynchronous calls made after the `startTest` method are collected by the system. When `stopTest` is executed, all `asynchronous` processes are run `synchronously`.

Hence, if you have your assert statements before `Test.stopTest()`, it won't pass because at that point of time, your batch wouldn't have been executed.

So whenever testing an `asynchronous` apex (its always a best practice whether asynchronous or synchronous), you should always have the assert statements after `Test.stopTest()` method.

You can find the significance of `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` at [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_start_stop_test.htm) link.

**Regarding the assert statements**

```
System.assertEquals(6, [Select count() from Account]);
```

This above assert statement seems to be correct, but the other one

```
for(Account a : [Select Name from Account] )
{
    System.assertEquals('Account '+i+' Updated by Batch', a.Name);
    i++;
}
```

I am not sure, this will always work because of following reasons

- Your batch only appends an integer, i.e. the value would be `Account 1` whereas you are asserting it with `Account 1 Updated by Batch`, which will fail, unless you are appending the value `Updated by Batch` from either Trigger/Workflow/Process Builder/Flow.
- When you are comparing the values fetched from the database, it is not always necessary that it will return the records in the same order in which it were inserted, i.e. if `Account 2` is retrieved first and if you are comparing it with `Account 1 Updated by Batch`, then again it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Batch, Future, Queuable, Scheduler are called Asynchronous apex. They run when the current transaction finishes and committed. There is no SLA for Async apex , ie they can run anytime, can be in few minutes or an hour.

While testing Async Apex, you have to demand that Async Apex should run asap in same transaction so that you can assert it.

This can be done by putting the invocation in between `Test.startTest();` and `Test.stopTest();`

Thus in your case. The asserting will be after the stop test.

```
@isTest
private class BatchTest
{
    static testMethod void testBatch()
    {
        List<Account> accs = new List<Account>();
        for(Integer i=1;i<=6;i++)
        {
            Account a = new Account();
            a.Name='Account '+i;
            accs.add(a);
        }
        insert accs;
        Test.startTest();
        Database.executeBatch(new BatchClass3());

        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(6, [Select count() from Account]);
        //System.assertEquals('Account 1 Updated by Batch',[Select Name from Account limit 1][0].Name);
        Integer i=1;
        for(Account a : [Select Name from Account] )
        {
            System.assertEquals('Account '+i+' Updated by Batch', a.Name);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Src: [How do I test asynchronous Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244791/how-do-i-test-asynchronous-apex)