# Test scheduled jobs

Tags: unit-test, scheduled

```
global class Animals implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        Selector.getAnimals();
        Calculator.setAnimals();
    }
}
```

And I want to perform the following test:

```
@isTest static void testCACKPIs() {
    SchedulableContext SC = new SchedulableContext();
    Animals.execute(SC);
}
```

But it is not working, first the error message says:

**Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context**

Comment: It helps if you format your code so it appears as code. I've done this for you this time, but I would like to see you start to do this. [The help page on formatting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) is a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

The `global` modifier doesn't change the fact that your `execute()` method is *still an instance method*.

`ClassName.method()` is how static methods are called.

Since `execute()` doesn't have the `static` modifier (and I don't think it should have that modifier anyway), you'll need to create an *instance* of your class to be able to call the *instance method*.

e.g.

```
MyClass classInstance = new MyClass();
classInstance.instanceMethod();
```

[How do I test asynchronous apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244791/how-do-i-test-asynchronous-apex) is also going to be a good resource for you in writing this test.

Answer (score 0):

I did finally like that:

```
global class Animals implements Schedulable {
**public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 * * * ? *';** 
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        Selector.getAnimals();
        Calculator.setAnimals();
    }
}
```

Adding this:

```
@isTest static void testAnimals() {
       Test.startTest();
          String jobId = System.schedule('testBasicScheduledApex',
          Animals.CRON_EXP, 
             new CAC_KPIs_Infomart());
          // Get the information from the CronTrigger API object
       CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime 
       FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :jobId];
       Test.stopTest();

       }
```