# i'm testing a batch. In the last block i have to verify that the list is not empty and the name equal to 'Kinder'. How can I do that?

Tags: unit-test, batch, class, developer, method

```
@isTest
public class QWE_Integration_BatchTest {
    public static testMethod void  metodoTest(){
        QWE_Integration__c rec = new QWE_Integration__c();            
        rec.First_Name__c = 'Kinder';
        rec.Last_Name__c = 'Lak';
        rec.Email__c = 'klak@gmail.com';        
    } 
    
    insert rec;
    
    Database.executeBatch(new QWE_Integration_Batch());
    
    List<Account> listAcc = [SELECT ID, Name from Account]; 
    
           
    // system.assert( .....)          
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you must wrap your batch invocation in `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()`, or your asynchronous code will not run inside the context of your unit test. See [How do I test asynchronous Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244791/how-do-i-test-asynchronous-apex) for more details.

Then, you must write assertions about what you believe to be true of the data in `listAcc` after your code has run. The reference for the [`System`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm) class explains all of the available assertion calls. In most cases, you'll want to use the form

```
System.assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue, message)
```

where `expectedValue` is what you think you should have, `actualValue` is the actual result, and `message` is a message to show if the assertion fails to clarify what is wrong.

Here, you might write two assertions that look something like this:

```
System.assertEquals(1, listAcc.size(), 'expected one Account');
System.assertEquals('Kinder', listAcc[0].Name, 'expected Account named Kinder');
```

We link numerous resources on how to write high-quality test code at [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test).