# Unable to cover test class for batch apex

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex

I'm unable to run the test class for Batch apex.

```
// This Schedule Class updates the Email Address of Inactive contacts whose Emp Termination date is over 30 days or Prac End date is Null

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        Database.executeBatch(this, 2000); 
    }
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        string InActive = 'InActive';
        string RecordType = 'RUSH';
        Boolean EmployeeterminationDate = TRUE;
        string query = 'select id, Email from Contact where Parent_Status__c =:InActive AND RecordType.Name=:RecordType AND Employee_Termination_DateMorethan_30Days__c=:EmployeeterminationDate AND Practitioner_Start_Date__c =NULL';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) { //Not able to run this block of code
        List<Contact> ConList = (List<Contact>) scope;
        for(Contact c : ConList){
            c.RUSH_Email__c = 'NotActive__' + c.ID+c.Email;
        }
            
        update ConList; // 
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        SchedulePractionerContactEmailUpdate PR = new SchedulePractionerContactEmailUpdate();
        id batchId = Database.executeBatch(PR);
    }
}
```

---

Test code

```
@istest
public class TestScheduleContactEmailUpdateHRDate {
    @istest static void ScheduleContactEmailUpdateHRDate(){
        Account ac= new Account();
        ac.Name = 'newtest';
        insert ac;
        
        contact con = new contact();
        con.LastName = 'Testcon';
        con.AccountId = ac.Id;
        con.ECHO_Active_Flag__c = FALSE;
        con.Email = 'test@test.com';
        con.RUSH_Email__c = 'test@test.com';
        date mydate = date.parse('12/01/2020');
        con.Employee_Termination_Date__c = mydate;
        insert con;
        
      /*    Test.startTest();
        ScheduleContactEmailUpdateHRDate cp = new ScheduleContactEmailUpdateHRDate();
        Database.executeBatch(cp, 2000);*/
        
        ScheduleContactEmailUpdateHRDate PR = New ScheduleContactEmailUpdateHRDate();
        Database.QueryLocator ql = PR.start(null);
        PR.execute(null);
        PR.Finish(null);
    }
```

Comment: "I'm unable to run" is not a valid question. Why are you not able to run it? What errors do you get? Please provide more information so we can assist you. You can read more about what we expect of a question in [ask].

Comment: You should take some time to read through [How to format](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). If the code you're providing isn't well-formatted, it makes it harder for people to read (and then makes it easier for them to decide your question isn't worth answering and move on). The name of the game here is "make it easy for people to help you".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility that your test could succeed, because you are calling `execute()`:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) { //Not able to run this block of code
```

with a `null` instead of the input this method requires:

```
    PR.execute(null);
```

You've also provided the wrong number of parameters, so this method call is being resolved to the `Schedulable` `execute()` method instead of the `Batchable` one.

I would suggest you review the resources available in [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) and [How do I test Asynchronous Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244791/how-do-i-test-asynchronous-apex) and make another attempt to write a functional unit test.